# The above query will not pull the information from the database

Tags: php, sql

```
$read = "SELECT * FROM elmtree 
WHERE id ='$getid' AND 
INNER JOIN elmtree_users ON elmtree.userid = elmtree_users.id";
```

The above query will not pull the information from the database to publish to the website.

Im trying to pull the item from the database with the $getid but also join the item id with the userid who uploaded it. Then using a while loop to print out the item to screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update the description and change “The above query will not pull the information from the database […]”; that should better say what *does* happen (an error? If so what is the exact error text? If not, what exactly happens instead?)

Comment: Generally speaking (tag your DBMS, please), your `inner join` needs to be before your `where` clause

Comment: You query is syntactically incorrect.  You have `AND` with nothing on the right.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The SQL syntax you show isn't correct. A join clause describes which tables will be available for the rest of the query; all tables you mention need to be part of the ‘FROM’ clause, so that is where the ‘JOIN’ also belongs.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM elmtree
    INNER JOIN elmtree_users ON elmtree.userid = elmtree_users.id
WHERE id ='$getid'
```

Comment: This throws no errors which is great, however it doesnt print anything to the webpage anymore. Its an white page now, the query is use din a while loop below

<?php
  
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
   
   $title = $row['title'];
   $price = $row['price'];
   $description = $row['description'];
   $imgpath = $row['path'];
   $posted = $row['posted'];
   $user = $row['user'];

Comment: @Lux, that sounds like a new question to ask. You can now describe the problem more exactly (by just talking about the SQL query) in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query was not correctly written. The `AND` is not used in joining tables and the `WHERE` statement should be after the `JOIN`.

Try the following:

```
$read = "SELECT * FROM elmtree INNER JOIN elmtree_users ON(elmtree.userid = elmtree_users.id) WHERE elmtree.id ='$getid'";
```

**UPDATE**

Could you try the following in your code (replacing `$this->database` with your database variable) and post the result:

```
if ($result = $conn->query($read)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
}
```

Comment: This throws an error with the while loop which prints the info to the webpage
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in 

<?php
  
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
   
   $title = $row['title'];
   $price = $row['price'];
   $description = $row['description'];
   $imgpath = $row['path'];
   $posted = $row['posted'];
   $user = $row['user'];

Comment: @Lux Could you post the part of your code with the SQL query?

Comment: so at the top of the webpage I have:

<?php

  include("conn.php");
  
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $getid = $_GET['id'];
  
 $read = "SELECT * FROM elmtree INNER JOIN elmtree_users ON(elmtree.userid = elmtree_users.id) WHERE elmtree.id ='$getid'";
  
//$read = "SELECT * FROM elmtree INNER JOIN elmtree_users ON elmtree.userid = elmtree_users.id";

 $result = $conn->query($read);
 // }else{
   
  // header('location: index.php');
   
 }
  
?>

and in the webpage body I have a while loop

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
   
   $title = $row['title'];
   $price = $row['price'];
   $description = $row['description'];
   $imgpath = $row['path'];
   $posted = $row['posted'];
   $user = $row['user'];

Comment: @Lux Before that. The code containing the SQL query.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $getid = $_GET['id'];
  
 $read = "SELECT * FROM elmtree INNER JOIN elmtree_users ON(elmtree.userid = elmtree_users.id) WHERE elmtree.id ='$getid'";

 $result = $conn->query($read);
   
 }

Comment: @Lux Could you try your code with `$read = "SELECT * FROM elmtree"` and let me know if it works?

Comment: Technically it works but it lacks the desired functionality. For example it pulls every item from the database and displays it on one page and it doesnt attach the item to the user who posted it.

I should be able to click on an item on the website and it should bring me to its item page with all the information on display, exactly like gumtree or ebay.

Comment: @Lux It was just a test, not an alternative. I updated my question. Could you test out the code and post the results?

Comment: The updated code doesnt display any errors. The query is working its just not populating the fields. Maybe if I explain the two tables.

Comment: @Lux Yea, please do cause no error means that there is no problem withe the query. Also, do you have related data in the two tables that would give the desired result?

Comment: Table elmtree has: itemid(PK), userid(FK), title, description, price etc
Table elmtree_users has: id(PK), user, email etc.

so although the qeury works in phpmyadmin it doesnt display any rows which is why the website is showing blank. I dont think the query is linking the "itemid" to the id of the user

Comment: The query does not match the given structure. Change `WHERE elmtree.id ='$getid'` to `WHERE elmtree.itemid ='$getid'` and let me know the results.

Comment: Good man, that did the trick! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Lux No problem!

Answer (score 0):

$read = "SELECT * FROM elmtree INNER JOIN elmtree_users ON(elmtree.userid = elmtree_users.id) WHERE elmtree.itemid ='$getid'

Big thanks to Omari Celestine to finding the answer to the problem!